# How to select just one option in RadioButtonList within a repeater with postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, radiobuttonlist

I have a `RadioButtonList` inside of `Repeater` and I want to select just one option at a time. But for each **RadioButtonList** created dynamically I can select multiple options in each **RadioButtonList**.

How can I select one option and deactivate the previous selection?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h4><label id="header" runat="server"><%# Eval("Description") %></label></h4>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdo" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdo_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="AutoID"></asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a control is rendering in a list bound control, the ID is changed to be unique so JavaScript can work with it.  There is a great forum post here about this, and it includes a work-around.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1378112.aspx?RadioButtonList+in+a+Repeater+GroupName

Comment: Thank you, this link have the solution, the second answer of the post is the correct. Thanks a lot.